# Почему jdbc соединение отсоединяется в некоторое время само собой

Tags: java, android, база-данных, jdbc, connection

Использую java и jdbc для установки соединения с базой данных.

Почему соединение отсоединяется в некоторое время само собой. Например программа соединяется к базе, работает отлично но если устройство не используется некоторое время то отсоединяется из базы. Пожалуйста напишите в чем проблема.

Comment: Вы работаете с jdbc на андроид? если нет уберите тег

Comment: Здравствуете да я работаю jdbc в android

Comment: Мое почтение сударь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервер базы данных может сам закрывать соединения, если они не используются. Поддерживать соединения для сервера не представляется возможным, поскольку он не может управлять клиентами, которые устанавливают эти соединения. Поэтому соединения закрываются независимо от того что вы используете для соединения jdbc, odbc, etc.

Для того чтобы поддерживать связь с сервером базы данных, клиент должен проверять наличие соединения, и в случае его отсутствия создавать новое. Можно написать метод, который возвращает только валидный объект `Connection`.

В некоторых базах данных можно сконфигурировать сервер, чтобы он переустанавливал соединение с клиентом самостоятельно.

Можно также воспользоваться библиотеками, которые позволяют управлять соединениями клиентов используя пулы соединений. Среди таких библиотек можно отметить dbcp, c3p0, и т.д.

Можно воспользоваться [примером](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/101342/) создания соединений используя известные пулы соединений.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 4):

Это штатное поведение JDBC соединения. Коннект с БД достаточно ресурсоемкий и ценный и просто так бронировать его надолго неразумно. Поэтому через какое-то время в случае неактивности клиента - коннект разрывается.

Начиная с JDBC 4.1 имеется новый метод `Connection.setNetworkTimeout()` в котором можно устанавливать время бездействия. В старых версиях это зависит от конкретного вендора СУБД/JDBC

P.S. Подучите немного русский - а то прямо глаза режет.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Здравствуете отвечаете пожалуйста все известное приложение как imo, facebook, vk как работает с база данных они утро до вечер не отсоединяется

Comment: Неужели вы думаете, что ваш клиент Facebook/VK устанавливают коннект с сервером через JDBC? :) Подсказка: они общаются через json поверх http :)

Comment: Тогда зачем нежна jdbc

Comment: JDBC нужен в приложениях, где БД находится "рядом" с сервером или по крайней мере когда с ним есть надежная связь. Например сервер приложений коннектится с сервером БД - это то самое место где нужен JDBC или настольное приложение, где БД находится в сетевом компе.

Comment: Спасибо вам вы мне помогли