# jdbc Как правильно закрывать соединение

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Как правильно закрывать соединение?  сейчас я делаю это так

```
try {
    
        
        PreparedStatement stQ = null;
        String query2 = "";
        stQ = conQ.prepareStatement(query2);

        rsQ = stQ.executeQuery();
        while (rsQ.next()) {

            }
        

       
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        conQ.close();
        System.out.println(conQ.isClosed());
    }finally {
          conQ.close();
          System.out.println(conQ.isClosed());
    }
     return
```

Нужно ли прописывать `close()` и в `cath` и `finally` блоках? Правильно ли я его впринципе закрываю?

и сколько времени длится само закрытие этого соединения?
В данный момент, я выполняю метод каждые 10 секунду( для теста) через пару минут вылетает ошибка о том, что достигнуто максимально кол-во подключений.
будет ли такой же итог, если я буду вызывать метод раз в 5 минут?

Comment: [Closing Database Connections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2225221/312041)

Comment: Сколько времени выполняется метод?

Comment: `finally` выполняется в любом случае. Поэтому в данном примере `conQ#close` в `catch` можно не прописывать. А чтобы получить время срабатывания `close`, можно как обычно до и после получить время и вычесть одно из другого.

Comment: @Roman C метод выполняется 44ms

Comment: @Sergey спасибо

Comment: За такое время соединение должно закрываться. А какое максимальное количество соединений превышено?

Comment: @Roman 110 шт, стоит ограничение в бд. То есть я где-то оставляю его открытым, раз подключения накапливаются за это время?

Comment: Значит за 2 мин можно открыть 60*2/10 = 12 соединений. Если открыть одновременно 9 потоков, то получим 118 соединений. Это превышает максимальное количество соединений. Поэтому все нормально, приходит ошибка подключения. Возможно надо переформулировать вопрос - как правильно открывать соединение. Причем возможно некоторые соединения могут закрываться в бд и это приводит к другой ошибке, см. [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1073064/204920) ответ.

Comment: @RomanC да, спасибо. уже разобрался что к чему, просто раньше, код был написан так, что даже прописывая в блоке finaly закрытие соединения, они оставались открытыми. исправил свои ошибки. спасибо

Comment: Соединения не могут оставаться открытыми если вы их создаёте сами. То, что вы неправильно понимаете конструкцию try - finally и повторно закрываете соединение после обработки исключения не относится к вашей проблеме. Просто незачем лишний раз закрывать соединение. Если в одном потоке вы используете соединение, а в другом пытаетесь его закрыть, то ничего у вас не выйдет. Поэтому в каждом потоке надо создавать новое соединение, а это увеличивает количество открытых соединений. Можно самому написать менеджер соединений или использовать уже существующий. См. ссылку из пред. комента.

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с 7-й версии Java, в ней появился новый оператор try-with-resources (try с ресурсами).
Он создан как раз для того, чтобы решать проблему с обязательным вызовом метода close(). В общем случае выглядит он довольно просто:

```
 try(
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(src);

    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dest))

    {
        byte[] buffer = input.readAllBytes();
        output.write(buffer);
    }
```

Из официальный документации:

public interface AutoCloseable

An object that may hold resources (such as file or socket handles) until it is closed. close()The method of an AutoCloseable object is called automatically when exiting a try-with-resources block for which the object has been declared in the resource specification header. This construction ensures prompt release, avoiding resource exhaustion exceptions and errors that may otherwise occur.

Comment: Не совсем понял, эту конструкцию нужно вызывать каждый раз при подключении? Благодаря чему оно само будет его закрывать?