# Частые запросы в базу данных, реализация

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Я пишу плагины для игрового сервера, и тут у меня возник вопрос, при использовании бд приходится заново открывать соединение с MYSQL, а запросы происходят часто, раз в 10 секунд точно(возможно и больше). И вопрос заключается в том, будет ли это производительно или прийти к другому решению. Я пытался сохранить подключение, но у меня ошибка вот код

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false", "user", "password")) {
            this.getLogger().info("MYSQL connected!");
            AccountManager.connection = connection;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the server!", e);
        }
```

Вот запрос.

```
public static HashMap<String, Object> executeSelect(String query) {
        try {
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet resultset = null;

            try {
                stmt = connection.createStatement();
                resultset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                if (stmt.execute(query)) {
                    resultset = stmt.getResultSet();
                }
                return resultSetToList(resultset);
            }
            catch (SQLException ex){
                // handle any errors
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                // release resources
                if (resultset != null) {
                    try {
                        resultset.close();
                    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { }
                    resultset = null;
                }

                if (stmt != null) {
                    try {
                        stmt.close();
                    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { }
                    stmt = null;
                }

            }

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Ошибка

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ConnectionIsClosedException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.checkClosed(NativeSession.java:1274)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:575)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createStatement(ConnectionImpl.java)
```

Comment: использовать hibernate

Comment: Рекомендую для чтения вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1073064/204920)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открытие соединения с БД это небыстрая операция: в лучшем случае один вызов по сети (а то и больше), для некоторых СУБД (например, postgres) - старт процесса для обслуживания запросов и его инициализация. И это все еще до того, как приложение сможет выполнить собственно запрос к БД, ради которого все и затевается.

Для этого есть решение - использование [пула соединений](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) (англ. connection pool).

Идея заключается в том, что программа запрашивает соединение не напрямую в БД, а через пул. Пул вначале создает соединение, как обычно, и возвращает программе.

Программа работает, как обычно используя JDBC (или любой ORM), но когда программа закрывает соединение, пул вместо того, чтоб его реально закрыть сохраняет его в список свободных к использованию соединений.

В следующий раз, например, при следующем запросе, пул отдаст готовое соединение, и не будет делать эту дорогостоящую операцию.

Дополнительное преимущество в том, что БД обычно не могут эффективно обрабатывать большое количество запросов одновременно, и пул соединений используется для ограничения одновременно открытых соединений и потому активных запросов к БД. Если приложение уже достигло лимита открытых приложений, то при запросе на открытие нового, оно будет ждать пока одно из используемых не будет возвращено в пул.

Примеры библиотек, реализующих пул соединений: [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) и [commons DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) и еще много других.

Приложению достаточно сконфигурировать пул и соединения создавать используя объект пула (вместо `DriverManager`). Пример для HikariCP:

```
// этот объект нужно создать один раз на все приложение  при старте 
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");
dataSource.setUsername("user");
dataSource.setPassword("password");
dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(10);  // так можно ограничить размер пула
```

В запросах использовать:

```
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
   this.getLogger().info("MYSQL connected!");
   // используем connection как обычно
}
```