# Как увеличить количество исходящих коннектов от генератора нагрузки к БД?

Tags: java, jmeter, groovy

Есть генератор нагрузки, на нем развернут джметр.
Почему то при отправке запросов в бд оракловую простым sql запросом можно пропустить лишь 100 потоков, которые выдают производительность в 90-95к запросов\сек, ставлю 101 поток, и производительность резко падает до 1к запросов в секунду, при тестах с 1000к потоков тоже самое.
Машинки с 32 цпу и 48 рам, в железо упора нет, с сетью тоже все норм. В чем может быть беда?
Схема скрипта:
Тред группа на 100 потоков
jdbc запрос с простым селектовым запросом без джоинов и подзапросов
jsr preprocessor ( в нем функция рандома от 1 до 1 млн)

Comment: Это нужно только для тестов, в реальной жизни 100 это вполне достаточно. Если ставить больше то смысла нет, они все равно отваливаются сами по себе и время от времени. Читай [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1073064/204920).